# Download json files from Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer to R

Tags: r, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, blobstorage

I'm triying to download data from my blob container.
First of all, I've used function '*blob_container*' to generate a blob container object as follows:

```
cont<blob_container('https://AccountName.blob.core.windows.net/BlobContainer',key='AccountKey')
```

Immediately, I've created a data frame to identify properly the path for each file.

```
list_files_blob<-list_blobs(cont, dir = "path where files are located")
```

Once I've collected all information,I've used 'multidownload_blob' function to copy that files to local path for local saving.

```
multidownload_blob(cont,src = list_files_blob$name ,dest = 'path to copy files',overwrite = T)
```

But I get this error.

```
Error: 'dest' must contain one name per file in 'src'
```

I know that there is a lot of files to trasnfer but I don't want to create a directory for each file but unique folder for all of them.

All functions are from *AzureStor* package.

My R version is 4.1.2 (2021-11-01)

```
"AzureStor": {
      "Package": "AzureStor",
      "Version": "3.7.0",
      "Source": "Repository",
      "Repository": "CRAN"
}
```

Thank you in advance.
Borja

Answer (score 0):

Finally,I've found an answer.
First of all,I've removed *dest* parameter from *multidownload_blob* function.
So, I've put all *json* files in the same folder as the working directory.
Once I've all the available information, I've used the following expression to create a new data frame (df)which is containing all the json files.

```
df<-fs::dir_ls(path=getwd(),regexp = "json")%>%
  map_df(fromJSON, .id = "ID",flatten=T)
```

I hope this works for all of us.
Borja